# does nginx auth_basic send the password plaintext?

Tags: security, encryption, nginx, .htpasswd

I am installing netdata with these instructions (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-real-time-performance-monitoring-with-netdata-on-ubuntu-16-04)

towards the end it uses `htpasswd` to create a user:password file that looks like it has been hashed in some way. If I look at the file I see...

```
username:$somekindofpasswordhashandnotthepasswordientered
```

The instructions then tell me to make a server block like this...

```
server {
    listen your_server_ip:80;
    server_name example.com;

    auth_basic "Authentication Required";
    auth_basic_user_file netdata-access;
```

`netdata-access` is the password file in the nginx conf directory. So when I visit this page and enter the password, am I sending my password plaintext over a network, or does the nginx module encrypt it somewhow? the server block is on port 80 and not 443...

EDIT: I took a quick read through the docs of both things and I found no information on my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auth_basic` works on the same connection opened when connecting to the server, so it's plain text on `http` and SSL/TLS encrypted on `https`. The only processing that takes place on the *user/pass* combination is a `Base64` encoding before being sent to the server.

You can use `curl` to see the headers:

```
$ curl -v -u your_user_name "http://......."
```

Look for the `> Authorization: Basic ...` line which contains a `Base64` encoding of `user:pass`.

You can decode the string using:

```
printf auth_string | base64 --decode
```

More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol).

---

Regarding the password file, `nginx` can use both clear text and hashed passwords in the password file ([info here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html)):

**1. Plain text:**

> ```
>     # comment
>     name1:password1
>     name2:password2:comment
>     name3:password3
> ```

**2. Encrypted/hashed:**

> - encrypted with the crypt() function; can be generated using the    “htpasswd” utility from the Apache HTTP Server distribution or the
>   “openssl passwd” command;
> - hashed with the Apache variant of the MD5-based password algorithm    (apr1); can be generated with the same tools;
> - specified by the “{scheme}data” syntax (1.0.3+) as described in [RFC    2307](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307#section-5.3); currently implemented schemes include PLAIN (an
>   example one,    should not be used), SHA (1.3.13) (plain SHA-1
>   hashing, should not be    used) and SSHA (salted SHA-1 hashing, used
>   by some software packages,    notably OpenLDAP and Dovecot).

```
$ htpasswd 
Usage:
    htpasswd [-cimBdpsDv] [-C cost] passwordfile username
    htpasswd -b[cmBdpsDv] [-C cost] passwordfile username password

    htpasswd -n[imBdps] [-C cost] username
    htpasswd -nb[mBdps] [-C cost] username password
 -c  Create a new file.
 -n  Don't update file; display results on stdout.
 -b  Use the password from the command line rather than prompting for it.
 -i  Read password from stdin without verification (for script usage).
 -m  Force MD5 encryption of the password (default).
 -B  Force bcrypt encryption of the password (very secure).
 -C  Set the computing time used for the bcrypt algorithm
     (higher is more secure but slower, default: 5, valid: 4 to 31).
 -d  Force CRYPT encryption of the password (8 chars max, insecure).
 -s  Force SHA encryption of the password (insecure).
 -p  Do not encrypt the password (plaintext, insecure).
 -D  Delete the specified user.
 -v  Verify password for the specified user.
On other systems than Windows and NetWare the '-p' flag will probably not work.
The SHA algorithm does not use a salt and is less secure than the MD5 algorithm.
```